# Google Apps Script debugger hangs when working with a specific string

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-apps-script, utf-8, freeze

I've run into a very peculiar bug and can't quite figure out what's wrong with it.

Here's the code that reproduces this issue:

```
function testDoubleQuote() {
  var xmlString = '<file><text>Ehf asor nkles pov ujfemniuea zeïerasvrtrw er Beaetrgfbvcyu Nbv., jei of asverqzsda vsdrersza vd. &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Ba erq vazerqhg nba lake erqybfa zvay rv asehgr va erqbu: “Er zhfa veqhazf qeyrreqgf?” Rq mnbsr ojgbeq pliyt mnbver zvae htwe nbrefpuk kj bmaner er mejreplrqv mneuijerbvce qtcx xi xghte hrfd erzemnbuyrewzsdez.</text></file>';
  var xml = XmlService.parse(xmlString);
  var content = xml.getAllContent();
  var text = content[0].getValue();
  console.log(text);
}
```

GAS hangs on the line with getValue(); Other attempts to get the text don't seem to work as well.  However, if I manually remove from the string either ï, “ or ” it seems to work. If I remove any two characters, it works again. What's going on? Is there a character limit to the string? Something else at work? The debugger just hangs.

A script I wrote to make a Javascript object from the XML object after parsing "works" in the sense that it creates the object. However, when attempting to view the text content of the object,the debugger never stops loading it. When I go through the process step by step, it hangs on getValue() or getText() or getChildText(name) when getting that specific text value. I guess it creates it because GAS largely runs asynchronously and the functions for those specific values just never return but that's for some reason ignored.

I can't seem to get any more info from GAS on what's going on. Is this caused by XmlService.parse()?

Comment: It doesn't hang for me.

Comment: I also tried this on my end and did not encounter the issue. Have you tried using a different internet connection? or a different account?

Comment: @RonM That's a great idea! I'll try a different account and recreate the environment in its entirety. Hopefully it's account related.

Comment: I am curious if adding a prolog to the start of the string makes any difference for you: `var xmlString = '<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" standalone = "no" ?><file><text>Ehf ... rewzsdez.</text></file>';`.

Comment: @andrewjames It had a prolog to begin with, but without the "standalone" part. I removed it to see if it changes anything.

Comment: @RonM Tried it again today and the error didn't show up. Before I even tried to create a new account. Which means it's the worst kind of error: one which showed up without change and stopped showing without it too.

Answer (score 1):

```
function testDoubleQuote() {
  var xmlString = '<file><text>Ehf asor nkles pov ujfemniuea zeïerasvrtrw er Beaetrgfbvcyu Nbv., jei of asverqzsda vsdrersza vd. &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Ba erq vazerqhg nba lake erqybfa zvay rv asehgr va erqbu: “Er zhfa veqhazf qeyrreqgf?” Rq mnbsr ojgbeq pliyt mnbver zvae htwe nbrefpuk kj bmaner er mejreplrqv mneuijerbvce qtcx xi xghte hrfd erzemnbuyrewzsdez.</text></file>';
  var xml = XmlService.parse(xmlString);
  var content = xml.getAllContent();
  //Logger.log(content.length);
  var text = content[0].getValue();
  Logger.log(text);
}

Execution log
1:52:09 PM  Notice  Execution started
1:52:10 PM  Info    Ehf asor nkles pov ujfemniuea zeïerasvrtrw er Beaetrgfbvcyu Nbv., jei of asverqzsda vsdrersza vd. <br /><br />Ba erq vazerqhg nba lake erqybfa zvay rv asehgr va erqbu: “Er zhfa veqhazf qeyrreqgf?” Rq mnbsr ojgbeq pliyt mnbver zvae htwe nbrefpuk kj bmaner er mejreplrqv mneuijerbvce qtcx xi xghte hrfd erzemnbuyrewzsdez.
1:52:10 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Very interesting. I wonder why it hangs for me. I tried it on different computers and browsers (not that it would make a difference, it shouldn't) and it still hangs. Could be something tied to the account or script.